# Tcp request failed with status 400 in Elastic Beanstalk Node Server with Nginx Proxy Server?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, tcp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
> 14.195.188.230 - - [18/Mar/2017:16:43:11 +0000] "(004026579154BP05000004026579154111213V0000.0000N00000.0000E000.0000000000.0010000000L0000021C)" 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

This is the error message that i received

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2017 02:19:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 173
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the log that i can see in my nginx access log, I need this data in my node server.

```
(004026579154BP05000004026579154111213V0000.0000N00000.0000E000.0000000000.0010000000L0000021C)
```

1) I am using elastic Beanstalk, i don't know how can i pass the above value to my node server module? If its possible to get that value as http or https request inside my node express module.

2) If i have to run a net server, than in which port should i listen for tcp, and how nginx will know about that port, for http server port, i use process.env.port